# Keyboard "Held" Event in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I found the methods to implement in any class that uses Key Listeners include keyPressed, keyReleased and keyDown, but how do I have it so that something happens continuously while the key remains pressed? Meaning is there a way to implement a "keyHeld" type scenario?

Comment: You mean `keyTyped` ? instead of `keyDown`.

Comment: to try add System.out.println() to the all KeyEvents, see whats happens, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with one Focusable JComponents, that react to KeyEvents

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be used with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

I have used a Swing Timer for this type of situation as you are now in full control over the repeat rate. You start the Timer with the keyPressed bindings and stop the Timer with the keyReleased binding. The Swing tutorial also has a section on How to Use Timers.

Answer (score 1):

There are two general mechanisms.

`keyPressed` will be repeatedly called while the key is held down, until the key is released. There is, however, normally a short delay between the first key press and repeat key.

Alternatively, you could set a flag that indicates that they key has bee pressed and resettle flag when it is released.

Probably the easiest solution for this would be to use some kind of `List` the contains al, the virtual key codes that are currently pressed. You would then just need to check this list to see if it contains the virtual key code you need to work with and take appropriate action when it does.

This leads me to the warning of, don't interact or change any UI component from any thread other then the Event Dispatching Thread

Answer (score 1):

The `keyTyped` method, gets called continuously while the key is down, with an initial delay:

```
s.....ssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```